# What is a good genetic algorithm (GA) or particle swarm optimisation (PSO) framework to use for .NET?

Tags: .net, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I would like to know what is a good, stable, framework that you guys suggest for implementing evolutionary optimisation techniques like PSO or GA?

I have written my own ones and I like them, I would be interested in comparing or adding to existing stable ones (or just using them if they are solid and extensible).

Answer (score 2):

Well, it depends on how sophisticated and complicated problems you need to solve, but in most cases the problem is such simple, that for example PSO algorithm is quite simple.

Maybe just try to find some good framework for matrix operations and implement it on your own?

But as I said, it all depends on the complexity of your problem. I used the PSO for quite simple problems (finding minimas of very complicated functions etc...) so I never needed any framework.

Answer (score 1):

Will the [Microsoft Solver Foundation](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/solverfoundation) help?

[Related Podcast:](http://hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=209)

Comment: Your welcome mate. Also check out this podcast
http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=209
In this particular show, a guy from the MSF team talks with  scott hanselman.